# Handling accounts and transaction signatures from nearlib

Tags: nearprotocol

I have a contract called `exchange`. A user, `Bob`, wants to spend `near tokens` to purchase positions in `markets` through the means of placing an `Order`. 
`Order` has a field called `owner`, it's important that the contract has proof that a certain `order` is owned by a certain address in this case `Bob`.

How transactions send to `exchange` are currently handled is a flow similar to:

```
const init = async () => {
  this.near = await window.nearlib.connect(Object.assign({ deps: { keyStore: new window.nearlib.keyStores.BrowserLocalStorageKeyStore() } }, window.nearConfig));
  this.walletAccount = new window.nearlib.WalletAccount(this.near);

  this.accountId = this.walletAccount.getAccountId();
  this.exchange = await this.near.loadContract(window.nearConfig.contractName, {
    viewMethods: [],
    changeMethods: ["place_new_order"],
    sender: this.accountId,
  });
}

await init();

// Bob logs into to near 
this.walletAccount.requestSignIn(
  window.nearConfig.contractName,
  window.nearConfig.contractName,
);

// Login process 
[...]

// Bob wants to place a new order
this.exchange.place_new_order(price, amount);
```

The `exchange` contract imports a `struct` called `Order`.

`Order` would look like:

```
use std::string::String;
use borsh::{BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize, Clone)]
pub struct Order {
    pub owner: String,
    pub amount: u64,
    pub price: u64,
}


impl Order {
    pub fn new(owner: String, amount: u64, price: u64) -> Self {
        Order {
            owner,
            amount,
            price
        }
    }
}
```

`Exchange` is, in this case, the contract that implements the mod `order`. `Exchange` has the `place_new_order` method which is where I want to be able to make sure that `Bob` is the one who sent the transaction:

```
  use near_bindgen::{near_bindgen, env};

  [...]

  mod Order;

  [...]

  pub fn place_new_order(&mut self, amount: u64, price: u64) {
    // Stuff happens here
    let order = Order::new(env::current_account_id(), amount, price);
    // Stuff happens here
  }
```

Now the thing is that in case, using this nearlib code `env::current_account_id()` will always return `exchange` as the `current_account_id`. This makes sense because all the login does is create an `access_key` which allows `exchange` to do a couple of things in the name of `Bob` but it's still `Exchange` signing off on transactions.

The question here is: How do I ensure that that exchange knows that `Bob` is the one who initialized the transaction?

A way this could work that would make sense:

- `Bob` signs every transaction with his private key, the question I'd have here is: how?

This would cause a Metamask-like UX problem where signing off on every tx is bad UX.

What I'd propose is the following:

- `Bob` uses a `deposit` method to deposit a set amount of `near-tokens` on `exchange` and `exchange` is allowed to spend that as long as it can proof that it's doing it through a "login-access-token" that is signed by `Bob`, the question here again is: is this possible and if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer

You should use `env::predecessor_account_id()` to get the account ID of a user or a contract who called a method on exchange.

### Details

In your case, even through the access key points towards the `exchange` it still signed by `bob. The`signer_id`and the`predecessor_id`during the execution are both going to be`bob`.

There are 3 different types of accounts during the execution:

- `env::current_account_id()` returns the current account ID of a contract that is executing right now.
- `env::signer_account_id()` returns the account ID of a user who signed the original transaction. Most of the time you should never rely on the signer account ID, cause the current call can be done from another contract.
- `env::predecessor_account_id()` return the account ID of immediate predecessor who called the current contract. You should use it to verify the identity of a user who called you.

Comment: Great that works, I wanted to test all account types but ran into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58642732/error-on-returning-environmental-account-ids